# Custom Role for all lambda in SST

Tags: node.js, aws-serverless

In my Current serverless application each role is getting assigned to lambda. If there are 200 lambdas, it means 200 roles will get created and I am using SST.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I need a common role for all the lambda functions

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet where you define the role and attach it to the functions?